# Tumblr API - OAuth issues: OAuth verifier and RESTConsole

Tags: api, rest, oauth, tumblr

Trying to obtain blog followers using Tumblr's API and RESTConsole in Chrome (not building an app, just want to check a request response).

I'm new to Tumblr's API and to RESTConsole, so two sources of possible error here.

I've already ...

1. Registered an app on Tumblr, receiving OAuth Consumer Key and Secret Key in the process.
2. Entered into REST Console my target: http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blogname}.tumblr.com/followers
3. Entered into REST Console's "Setup oAuth" window my OAuth Consumer Key and Secret Key, along with Tumblr's Request Token URL, Access Token URL and Authorize URL.
4. Approved read/write access to my application when prompted by Tumblr.
5. Entered the provided Token Key and Token Secret into REST Console's oAuth window.

When I attempt GET requests for follower counts (on my own blog or others'), Tumblr returns 401, "Not Authorized." My blog's preferences page lists the application I'm trying to use as having access.

I've tried this placing base-hostname:{blogname}.tumblr.com in REST Console's request parameters fields; I receive the same error. I tried running a different OAuth method from Tumblr's API (queued posts) and receive the same error.

Help?

Thanks. Let me know if this isn't clear.

Edit: Sorry, meant to add -- I think I may need Oauth Verifier. I haven't been able to find this token, or understand how to obtain it.

**Edit (2): So, turns out Tumblr's API needs a comma separator from the REST Console. Thanks all.**

''

Zack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$conskey = "CONSUMER KEY";
$conssec = "CONSUMER SECRET";

$tumblr_blog = "myblog.tumblr.com";
$to_be_posted = "This is the text to be posted";

$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
$oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/following", array('offset'=>0) ,OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET);

$result = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());

foreach($result->response->blogs as $key){
  echo $key->url;
}
```

The code above will retrieve your followers list.

Hope this helps.